# $http post call OPTIONS not post?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, ionic-framework

Hello so i'm trying to call my backend and getting some strange issue with calling post method.

> ```
> Remote Address:192.168.58.183:80
> Request URL:http://192.168.58.183/ESService/ESService.svc/CreateNewAccount
> Request Method:OPTIONS
> Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
> Request Headersview source
> Accept:*/*
> Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
> Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pl;q=0.6
> Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
> Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
> Connection:keep-alive
> Host:192.168.58.183
> Origin:http://localhost:8100
> Referer:http://localhost:8100/
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) >      AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.93
> Safari/537.36
> Response Headersview source
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Accept
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST,GET,OPTIONS
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
> Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000
> Allow:POST    
> Content-Length:1565
> Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
> Date:Mon, 02 Feb 2015 09:11:17 GMT
> Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
> X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
> ```
>
> And my code looks like here i think this call is okay can someone review it?

```
$scope.RegisterUser = function(){
var us = {
  UserName:$scope.userName,
  Password:$scope.password,
  UserRoleID:null,
  Company:$scope.company,
  Terms:$scope.terms,
  ID:null,
  BuyerID:app.buyerId
};

$http({method:'POST', url:app.wcf + '/CreateNewAccount', data:{us:us}})
.then(
    function(resp){
     app.Logger(resp.data);
    },
    function(err){
      app.Logger(err);
})};
```

So maybe i'm doing something wrong or i need to pass optional config to http?

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Comment: I think i allowed it on backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, browsers will not allow your site's JavaScript to read the data from a cross-origin request. This is because your site might be instructing the browser to get information from the user's online banking, company intranet, or some other private site. This is called [The Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

A standard called [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) allows a site to give permission to another site to read data from it.

Since POST requests can have side effects, an additional layer of security is added. Before the browser will make the POST request, it will make a [pre-flight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) to ask for permission to make the POST request.

Your server is not configured to handle that OPTIONS request (and probably isn't configured to return the CORS headers for the POST request either).

You need to set up CORS support if you want to allow your JavaScript to make requests to it from a different origin.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pre flight request and is used to enable CORS there is no need to be concerned this is normal.

Comment: But im getting XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.58.183/ESService/ESService.svc/CreateNewAccount. Invalid HTTP status code 405

Comment: I feel like that's more of an issue with the configuration of your api